# How to enter a value in a list with js script and select an item in it

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver

I use https://www.carpages.ca  page for studying Selenium Web. I'm trying to enter 'Ottawa' in the location control and then select 'Ottawa, ON'.

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement( By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'tt-hint')]"));  // or "//*[contains(@class, 'tt-input')]"
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
String     cityName = "Ottawa";
actions.sendKeys(el, cityName, Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

But 'Ottawa' string is not entered in the location control so I am not able to Keys.Down and Keys.ENTER to select 'Ottawa, ON'.
Also I've tried the code below with the same results (nothing is selected in the location control):

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (FirefoxDriver) driver;
        jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('used_city').setAttribute('type', 'text');");
        jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('used_city').setAttribute('value', 'Ottawa');");
         WebElement el = driver.findElement( By.xpath("//*[@id=\"used_city\"]"));
        el.sendKeys( Keys.DOWN);
```

It seems that the location control has some script that invoked and returns a location value. Could anyone tell me how it is possible to enter a value if a control has some script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is tricky as far that site has bug. If you click and start typing, your value would be reset to that strange location.

To avoid it you should click on input with locator `#js-search-form input.tt-input`, perform Enter and wait for value to appear and then clear it.

After that you should a bit slow-down execution by entering chars one by one to grant ability for resource to process your value.

Then you should click on input to trigger suggestions list and select first one.

Be aware that it is not good practice to write such workarounds on real bugs. It is only valid for scraping, not autotesting purposes.

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement input = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#js-search-form input.tt-input")));
String town = "Ottawa";
actions.moveToElement(input).click().perform();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return document.querySelector('#js-search-form input.tt-input').value || undefined"));
input.clear();
for (Character ch: town.toCharArray()) {
    actions.sendKeys(input, ch.toString()).perform();
}
input.click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("w-suggestions")));
actions.sendKeys(input, Keys.DOWN).perform();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

Comment: @ Yaroslavm, thank you for your answer. I tried your code. I see that 'Ottawa' is entered into the location control and 'Ottawa, ON' and 'Ottawa Brook, N'S items appears in dropdown list. But after actions.sendKeys(input, Keys.ENTER).perform(); the control has the default value 'Gloucester, ON'. I've tried to add         actions.sendKeys(input, Keys.DOWN).perform();  actions.sendKeys(input, Keys.ENTER).perform();  to select item in dropdown list but no success. Is there is anything else I should do to have 'Ottawa, ON' item selected? @Yaroslavm

Comment: @IdurJul I updated snippet and explanation, please, check it.

Comment: Your code works better then mine. Thank you. I tried it and see that each letter of 'Ottawa' word appears one by one, erasing the previous one. And final 'a' letter corresponds to 'Abbotsford, BC' item. So, I've changed your code. If I  have 'String town ="o";' then  'Ottawa, ON' and 'Ottawa Brook, N'S items appears in dropdown list and the first item is selected. I'm lucky I have the required item located at the first position in dropdown. If I need the second item I should double the line with 'actions.sendKeys(input, Keys.DOWN).perform();' code. Okey, I can use this WA. Thank U! @Yaroslavm

Comment: But nevertheless, this is WA, and the autotest can be easily broken if a new element is added to the drop-down list. I'm just wondering how good this solution is and how often such alternative could be used.

Comment: @IdurJul dropdown item can easily be selected by text / index, there is no problem with it. Using keyboard keys is the laziest (and not the best) solution. Btw, are you sure you copied my code as is? As fat as it shouldn't erase. It would erase if you would use input.sendKeys(), not in case actions.sendKeys(input, key);

Comment: Dropdown items have selector `.suggestions__item` , so you can filter them and get one that contain your text, that is the better solution than performing arrow down.

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(new By.ByClassName("suggestions__item")))
                        .stream().filter(el -> el.getText().contains(town)).findFirst().get().click();

Comment: @ Yaroslavm, Yes, that works perfectly! It is what I needed. Thank you.